# .htaccess RewriteRule execute php script when image loads

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

So I've been working on creating a webbug inside a laravel project that would log basic information whenever any image is loaded. However, my .htaccess document doesn't seem to be recognizing my extensions correctly as it's not executing my script. I know my script works as when I run it, the database gets new inputs. The script itself just isn't getting called. I'm using Blade Templates to create views that execute on a route resource or for testing in this case, a specific route.

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('identifyVerification', 'PhishingController');
Route::get('/breachReset','PhishingController@breachReset');
Route::get('/breachReset/verifyUser', 'PhishingController@breachVerify');

Route::get('/path/to/sec_question.png','PhishingController@imageReturnTest');
```

The testing route that I'm using is the last one, @imageReturnTest. It references a function in PhishingController that is defined as shown below. It is opening a test image I have in an img directory inside my public directory.

```
public function imageReturnTest() {
        $path = './img/sec_question.png';
        $fp = fopen($path,'rb');
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
        fpassthru($fp);
        exit;
    }
```

When this image loads, my .htaccess file is to see that an image with the extension .png loaded and then run a redirect to execute the webbug_test.php page. Below is my .htaccess file inside of laravel. My rule should execute not just on PNGs but any image (JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc. - extensions can be added as needed). As you can see, I've tried to solutions that I've found via StackOverflow and other websites describing how to set up a Transparent Webbug. Both haven't worked.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # My new rule to execute webbug
    RewriteRule ^(.*).(png|jpg|gif)$ webbug_test.php

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I've also tried this for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /webbug_test.php
```

Below is my webbug_test.php script that should be getting called via the .htaccess. As I've said, I can run this page through the IDE tester and it will run it's SQL execution and insert into the database the appropriate information for it's impromptu execution. However, it doesn't get called when an image loads.

**webbug_test.php**

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo 'Error: Could not connect to the database..';
exit;
}

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$reqpath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$browseragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s");
print "vars created";
$sql = "INSERT INTO database.table (id,ip,host,
   browser_agent,req_path,access_date,access_time) VALUES 
   (null,'$ip','$host','$browseragent','$reqpath','$date',
   '$time');";
print "sql executed";
$result = $db->query($sql);

$result->free();
$db->close();

header( 'Content-type: image/jpg' );
?>
```

**Image of SQL Results** 
[image: SQL Results]

With all of this said, I'm unsure as to how to move forward to push this redirect. I've looked at executing a name scheming that would make this script think it's an image then do a RuleRewrite to execute .jpg as php scripts, however, I still want the requested image to be displayed and I don't want to have to format my script to received piped data and return the requested image on top of the SQL insert. Any feedback on what I may be doing wrong or how I can better implement a global webbug?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dynamic php file that will serve images and log other details to database. 
Example 
`<img src="image.php?name=abc.jpg />` and log your data from image.php.

Comment: Does it need to actually pass the image to work or could this function as a transparent webbug? I think I had tried this before and it was giving me problems, however, I might not have implemented it correctly.

Comment: you just need to pass image name and get that name in php file using $_GET. It should work.